# How to resize a WPF user control used in Winform When the Winform application resizes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, telerik

i am new to wpf and using a wpf user control in a winform application inside a `system.windows.forms.tabpage` .

wpf control code

```
  <UserControl x:Class="VMS_TimelineControl.WpfTimeline"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VMS_TimelineControl"
         xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
         mc:Ignorable="d" Height="161" Width="1135" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Name="usercontrol">

   <Grid Name="grid" Margin="0,0,10.085,0.489" Height="153" Width="1125">

      <Grid.Resources>

      </Grid.Resources>

      <telerik:RadTimeline x:Name="Timeline" Height="153" Width="1125"
      </telerik:RadTimeline>

   </Grid>

 </UserControl>
```

Winform Code Using This Control

```
        timeLine = new WpfTimeline();
        TimeLineData data = new TimeLineData();
        data.startdate = StartTime;
        data.enddate = EndTime;
        data.DataToPlot = events;          
        timeLine.DataContext = data;

        timeLine.SendEventDateTime += TimeLinePlayVideo;
        //Elementhost ----> host for timeline control in winforms
        this.timelineHost.Height = ((int)timeLine.Height) + 10;
        this.timelineHost.Width = (int)timeLine.Width;
        this.timelineHost.Child = timeLine;
        this.timelineHost.BringToFront();            
        tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.timelineHost);
        //tabPage1  is the tab inside whos tabpage this wpf control is hosted.
```

now i want to resize the wpf control when the winform app. window is resized. The tabpage resizes but wpf control does not. 
how do i do it.??

tabpage screenshot when window full size

[image]

when window resized
[image]

please help.

Comment: Not sure this is what you need but try by wrapping the `telerik:RadTimeline` inside a `ViewBox`.

Comment: @Pragmateek can i somehow bind the `height` and `width` property of `<Usercontrol/>` to the height and width of tabpage ??

Comment: Probably but I think you should try with layout components like the `ScrollViewer` or the `ViewBox`. To test them you just have to wrap your `telerik:RadTimeline` in them. You'll quickly see if one fits your needs ... or no. :)

Comment: @Pragmateek I tried `Viewbox` but it dosent fit my needs. And i don't want to use `ScrollViewer` since the the `timeline` already has it own scrollbar.